# Need to find the number of li elements which uses ng-repeater in protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

I need to find the length of li elements in protractor

My View is

```
<ul id="list">
<li ng-repeat="class in classList.classInfo.values() | orderBy:'displayOrder'">
</li>
</ul>
```

I tried this

```
element.all(by.repeater('class in classList.classInfo.values()| orderBy:"displayOrder"')).count().then(function (count) {

}
```

But I am getting wrong value of count. 
What is the best way of finding number of li element in this scenario using protractor?

Comment: Could you expand on the wrong value you are being given?

Comment: It seems like the element is not rendered in DOM when test scripts are executed. Is it better to use browser.wait method and check for specific element to be loaded before executing the test scripts?

Comment: If you're testing an AngularJS application, you could use     browser.waitForAngular();    or if you're not, you can use    browser.sleep(5000);     for example

Answer (score 1):

Try using a $$('') selector, this is short for element.all(by.css('...')):

```
var foo = $$('[ng-repeat="class in classList.classInfo.values() | orderBy:\'displayOrder\'"]');
    foo.then(function(bar){
        console.log(bar.length);
    });
```

Comment: It seems like the element is not rendered in DOM when test scripts are executed. Is it better to use  browser.wait method and check for specific element to be loaded before executing the test scripts?